# ObjectInputStream is giving NullPointerException error inside the AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, serialization, android-asynctask, deserialization, objectinputstream

My purpose is to **deserialize** a binary file inside the **AsyncTask** since it is a heavy process that freezes my Android GUI.

Web Service serializes the Weka Classifier class. Then, I am getting a binary file through Web Service and I am going to deserialize the binary file so that I can continue to process other Weka calculations.

I have achieved to receive the serialized binary file and deserialize in my Android App. Then, I realized that deserialization and reading process takes time. Therefore, I have decided to show Progress Dialog to the user by using AsyncTask.

And, here comes the issue. When I implement the deserialization process inside the **doInBackground** method, I get a **NullPointerException** error.

***Android Code:***

```
public class MatlabMainWindow extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button treeButton;
private Button positionButton;
private TextView textViewTree;
private PositionDetector positionDetector;
private String treeHolder;
private Classifier j48ClassifierHolder;

File sdcardFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_matlab_main_window);

    treeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tree);
    positionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_position);
    textViewTree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_tree);


treeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask(MatlabMainWindow.this);
            task.execute();

        }
    });

    positionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String positionString = positionDetector.calculateThePosition();

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MatlabMainWindow.this);
                alert.setTitle("Position Prediction");
                alert.setMessage(positionString);
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public BackgroundTask(MatlabMainWindow activity) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
        dialog.show();

    // getting the binary file through web service
    ...
    ...

        Volley.newRequestQueue(MatlabMainWindow.this).add(binaryHttpRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        textViewTree.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textViewTree.setText(treeHolder);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // deserialize model
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(sdcardFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/Weka/dataset_RFKON/j48.model"));

                j48ClassifierHolder = (Classifier) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //try {
        //
        //        treeHolder = j48ClassifierHolder.toString();
        //    } catch (Exception e) {
        //        e.printStackTrace();
        //    }


        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

***Error:***

```
W/System.err:     at inovasyonwebservice.com.gezkonwebservice.Matlab.MatlabMainWindow$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(MatlabMainWindow.java:250)
W/System.err:     at inovasyonwebservice.com.gezkonwebservice.Matlab.MatlabMainWindow$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(MatlabMainWindow.java:155)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at inovasyonwebservice.com.gezkonwebservice.Matlab.MatlabMainWindow$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(MatlabMainWindow.java:264)
W/System.err:     at inovasyonwebservice.com.gezkonwebservice.Matlab.MatlabMainWindow$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(MatlabMainWindow.java:155)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worke
```

**Note**: There is no problem about deserialization process, file location or file permisssion because it runs in **MatlabMainWindow** class perfectly

**EDIT1:** 
I have just commented the toString() part to investage reading part closer, the main error that I was getting actually is this one:

```
W/System.err: java.io.EOFException
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:83)
W/System.err:     at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:147)
```

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: Check for the object being null because null.toString() will give you a null pointer exception.

Comment: I have tracked it. And, when I try to read by using **readObject()** method **EOFException**. Still no idea why because I can read that file everywhere but inside the doInBackground().

Comment: `I have tracked it.`. Can be. But you should check for nul;l before use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, I have figured out what went wrong. There are main 3 part in my doInBackground() method, which are getting the binary file through Web Service, reading and deserializing the binary file and converting my object into a string.

I found out that getting the binary file and converting deserilized object into a string confuses readObject() method somehow. Thus, I isolated these 2 process by placing the Web Service part into onCreate() and placing also the string conversion part in to onPostExecute().

Here is the final code:

```
public class MatlabMainWindow extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button treeButton;
private Button positionButton;
private TextView textViewTree;
private PositionDetector positionDetector;
private String treeHolder;
private Classifier j48ClassifierHolder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_matlab_main_window);

    treeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tree);
    positionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_position);
    textViewTree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_tree);

    BinaryHttpRequest binaryHttpRequest = new BinaryHttpRequest(....)

    Volley.newRequestQueue(MatlabMainWindow.this).add(binaryHttpRequest);

    treeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask(MatlabMainWindow.this);
            task.execute();
        }
    });

    positionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String positionString = positionDetector.calculateThePosition();

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MatlabMainWindow.this);
                alert.setTitle("Position Prediction");
                alert.setMessage(positionString);
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public BackgroundTask(MatlabMainWindow activity) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
            treeHolder = positionDetector.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textViewTree.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textViewTree.setText(treeHolder);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        positionDetector = new PositionDetector();
            try {
        // reading the binary file here 
                positionDetector.getTrainData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to check this part of code:

```
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(sdcardFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/Weka/dataset_RFKON/j48.model"));

            j48ClassifierHolder = (Classifier) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
```

I think that the field *j48ClassifierHolder* statys null due to an exception, which causes *j48ClassifierHolder.toString()* to throw **NullPointerException**.
And the fact that you try/catch this part, you have to check your logcat for the exception before the **NullPointerException**.

Comment: I have just commented out to look into the part that you have suggested. Actually, the main error was java.io.EOFException. It seems it cannot find the end of the file but I still couldn't figure it out...